# Submitting to a web form using python

Tags: python, post, request, urllib2, urllib

I have seen questions like this asked many many times but none are helpful

Im trying to submit data to a form on the web ive tried requests, and urllib and none have worked

for example here is code that should search for the [python] tag on SO:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'

# Prepare the data
values = {'q' : '[python]'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)

# Send HTTP POST request
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

html = response.read()

# Print the result
print html
```

yet when i run it i get the html soure of the home page

here is an example of using requests:

```
import requests

data= {
    'q': '[python]'
    }
r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com', data=data)

print r.text
```

same result! i dont understand why these methods arent working i've tried them on various sites with no success so if anyone has successfully done this please show me how!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sounds like a job for [tag:mechanize-python]!

Comment: yeah ill check that out but i'm still wondering why these wont work!?

Comment: Php seems easier and more intuitive

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to pass `q` as a parameter in the URL using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/), use the `params` argument, not `data` (see [Passing Parameters In URLs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls)):

```
r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com', params=data)
```

This will request https://stackoverflow.com/?q=%5Bpython%5D , which isn't what you are looking for.

You really want to *`POST`* to a *form*. Try this:

```
r = requests.post('https://stackoverflow.com/search', data=data)
```

This is essentially the same as *`GET`*-ting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python , but I think you'll get the idea from this.

Comment: wow that actually worked i tried alot bu i didnt know why i couldnt get it thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
      'location' : 'Northampton',
      'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
the_page = response.read()
```

This makes a POST request with the data specified in the values. we need urllib to encode the url and then urllib2 to send a request.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize library from python is also great allowing you to even submit forms. You can use the following code to create a browser object and create requests.

```
import mechanize,re
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)   # ignore robots
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  # can sometimes hang without this
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]             
br.open( "http://google.com" )
br.select_form( 'f' )
br.form[ 'q' ] = 'foo'
br.submit()
resp = None

for link in br.links():
    siteMatch = re.compile( 'www.foofighters.com' ).search( link.url )

    if siteMatch:
        resp = br.follow_link( link )
        break

content = resp.get_data()
print content
```

Comment: Is there a way to update this and make this work?