# how to pass textarea value as parameter of url request in python

Tags: python-2.7, httprequest, httpresponse

this question may have been discussed somewhere else already but just want to get some refreshment from here:
I have a list (sourse.csv) with bunch of records that all have 3 fields like: ID, Name1, Name2
I need to look up them in a website abcde.com to validate them
ID and Name1 correspond to two textboxes on the web page while Name2 is for a textarea

There is a Submit button on the page

Once my python code parses the validation result, I need to write it into a local file (result.csv).

Can anyone enlighten me on how to write the script? especially how to mock up the httprequest with parameters for the textboxes and textarea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17509607/3657941) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17509879/3657941). If you really need someone to write a script for you, try [freelancer](https://www.freelancer.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I am not looking for freelance but rather to do that myself