# python urllib2.Request or urllib2.urlopen seems cutting response

Tags: python, request, response

I need to write a python script to do some validation on GSH number, the page is here: https://www.businessregistration-inscriptionentreprise.gc.ca/ebci/brom/registry/registryPrompt.do

As you can see there are three parameters to be provided. My script is as below (thanks to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509879/3657941)):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.businessregistration-inscriptionentreprise.gc.ca/ebci/brom/registry/registryPromptSubmit.do'
values = {'businessNumber' : 'Michael Foord',
      'businessName' : 'Northampton',
      'requestDate' : '2016-10-23' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

I inspect the result and it shows the response ends with something like these:
, here is a screenshot:
[image]

What happened to the response? where is the mainContentOfPage indicated in the  right after the  section?

Thank you very much.

Comment: your link shows me "404 File not found"

Comment: Maybe it is because the page asked user to click on something to confirm, here is the previous page: [link](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/esrvc-srvce/tx/bsnss/gsthstrgstry/trms-eng.html), thank you for your finding, this maybe the cause.

Comment: probably this page use JavaScript/AJAX to add elements on page. `urllib`/`urllib2`/`requests` doesn't run scripts.

Comment: I also checked the text between the <main role....> and <link rel....>, they are as following: 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 09 09 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a

Comment: `0d 0a` is hex code of enter - new line, `20` is hex code of space.

Comment: Can you tell how to mock the button click in the previous page? I guess I need to run that first in the python script

Comment: the reason I check the hex code is to ensure there is no EOF kind of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126560/discussion-between-paslechoix-and-furas).

Comment: use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see data send from browser to server. "I agree" button sends "POST" with "iagree=yes"

Comment: maybe this button save info as  cookies - it is easier to work with cookies (and session) using `requests` module. BTW. form on your page sends `action=Search` so server may check it too.

Comment: can we move to the chatting room? [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126560/discussion-between-paslechoix-and-furas), thanks.